# How to return Observable from a generated array?

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I create an array "organizationNamesAndIds" using the below code.
How do I return this value as an observable?

```
getOrganizationNameAndId(): Observable<Array<{ text: string, value: number }>> {        

  var organizationNamesAndIds = new Array<{ text: string, value: number }>();

   var organization : IOrganization = <IOrganization> {};
   organization.isActive = true;

   this.getOrganizations(organization).subscribe((organizations: IOrganization[]) => {

    organizationNamesAndIds.push({ text: organization.name, value: organization.id })

    // need to return organizationNamesAndIds

   });

   return  Observable.from(organizationNamesAndIds).bufferCount(organizationNamesAndIds.length);

}
```

What I am trying to return is the array of objects as an observable how do I do this?

After I get the value I can just set it by calling the function

```
 this.organizationService.getOrganizationNameAndId().subscribe((organizationNamesAndIds)=> {
      populateOrganizationOptions.options = organizationNamesAndIds}
    );
```

Comment: You might try `Observable.of` instead of `Observable.from`. `from` creates an event for each element in the array, `of` will create an event of the whole array.

Comment: what does your `getOrganizations` look like

Comment: what is the purpose of using bufferCount?